# In a Python doc string, is it customary to align the --'s in the argument list?

Tags: python

For example:

```
def foo(length, width):
    """Short desc.

    Arguments:

    length -- A desc.
    width  -- A desc.
    """
```

Note how I have added an extra space after "width".

Comment: My general rule of thumb is not to do things like this, because it makes maintenance painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a convention about this.  All [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) says about the docstring of a function is

> The docstring for a function or method should summarize its behavior and document its arguments, return value(s), side effects, exceptions raised, and restrictions on when it can be called (all if applicable). Optional arguments should be indicated. It should be documented whether keyword arguments are part of the interface.

The only example given in the PEP also doesn't shed light on the matter:

```
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    """Form a complex number.

    Keyword arguments:
    real -- the real part (default 0.0)
    imag -- the imaginary part (default 0.0)

    """
    if imag == 0.0 and real == 0.0: return complex_zero
    ...
```

I usually do align the dashes, but I don't think there is a general convention.

Comment: This is a slightly different issue, but I know that Guido doesn't like aligning the equal signs in a series of assignments, so the only vaguely alignment-like precedent I can think of goes the other way.  I tend to align them [docstring arg names, I mean] if there's not too wide a range in length involved.

Comment: Looking through the source of the standard library gives some better examples. The dashes aren't aligned.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a matter of choice.

Many people actually use [ReST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReST) in their docstrings and then generate documentation using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/). In this case there might be some requirements but I don't think alignment of dashes is one of them.

I don't like the idea of aligning things since it makes diffs extremely ugly as soon as you add something that requires you to realign many lines.

Answer (score 0):

I like your example (aligning the --) and think it makes the docstring easier to read at a glance.

There is no PEP 8 style standard for this, so what you end-up doing is largely a matter of taste.  That being said, there are some precedents in the standard library.  For example, the following is taken from the docstring for the [poplib module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6099d9dd0c26/Lib/poplib.py#l36):

```
class POP3:

    """This class supports both the minimal and optional command sets.
    Arguments can be strings or integers (where appropriate)
    (e.g.: retr(1) and retr('1') both work equally well.

    Minimal Command Set:
            USER name               user(name)
            PASS string             pass_(string)
            STAT                    stat()
            LIST [msg]              list(msg = None)
            RETR msg                retr(msg)
            DELE msg                dele(msg)
            NOOP                    noop()
            RSET                    rset()
            QUIT                    quit()

    """
```